# Getting a variable from inside a method java

Tags: java

I am new to Stack and have just started learning java. When I was trying a simple project, I came across a problem like this.

I have a main class here (**MainClass.java**)

```
public class MainClass
{
public void myNumber()
{
String var1="Data";

}

}
```

This is my second class (**SecondClass**)

```
public class SecondClass
{
public void data()
{
String dataFromPrevClass="";//This is where I want to get the value of 'var1' from the previous class
System.out.println(dataFromPrevClass);

}

}
```

I know that this question sounds really dumb, but inspite of a lot of searching, I was not able to find a solution to this. Please help me. I tried using a constructor like `MainClass Mainclass=new MainClass();` and then tried something like `String var2=Mainclass.var1`, but this didnt work.

Comment: You need to change your method to `public String myNumber()
{
return "Data";
}`

Comment: Or change the variable so it is a field in the class, instead of a local variable in the method.

Comment: The usual way for methods to receive and return information is by passing them through parameters and using the return value. See: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help :), I was able to figure it out

Comment: Well, this is one of the basic things about programming – passing data to somewhere else. I suggest you to study the basics of the Java language. I personaly like [the Oracle Java Tutlrials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either return from method and use it in the second class or create static var,

```
public class MainClass
{
    public String myNumber()
    {
        String var1="Data";
        return var1;
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public void data()
    {
        String dataFromPrevClass=new MainClass().myNumber();
        System.out.println(dataFromPrevClass);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static String var1="Data";
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public void data()
    {
        String dataFromPrevClass= MainClass.var1;
        System.out.println(dataFromPrevClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `var1` is only visible inside of its scope/block:

```java
private void myMethod() {
    System.out.println(beru); // This doesn't work. beru is not yet visible for this line of code
    String beru = "Beru"; // here we create a variable beru.
    // every following line can see beru
    System.out.println(beru);
} // this is the end of myMethod() a.k.a end of a scope/block
```

If you want to get access to a variable that's inside of another method. You have to ask the method to return something.

```java
private String whatIsMyName() {
    return "Beru";
}


String name = whatIsMyName() // now name contains "Beru"
```